# AppID on X86 OR X64! Different or Same?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am writing an install with Inno Setup. I am doing both an x86 version and a x64 version for Windows.

My Questions is do Create a different AppID Guid for each install on each platform (x86, x64) or do I use the Same AppID for each seeing as the Apps are the Same just compiled for both x86 and x64?

Answer (score 2):

If they are separate installs (and can co exist), or you want to detect the other architecture, then use to separate AppIDs.
If the install is one or the other, then use the same AppID.

Note that there isn't normally any reason to make two separate installs as Inno can handle any architecture differences with very similar legwork to individual installs.